# Voiding an envelope using the new DocuSign C# Client

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to void an existing envelope using the updated version of the [DocuSign C# Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) (DocuSign.eSign).

The envelope is in the Sent status and has not been completed or voided already.

Currently I have following code:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

Envelope envelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId);           
envelope.Status = "voided";
envelope.VoidedReason = "This envelope was voided by " + currentUserName;

// create the recipient view (aka signing URL)
var updateSummary = envelopesApi.Update(accountId, envelopeId, envelope);

return updateSummary;
```

When this code is called, it fails with an ApiException and the following ErrorContent:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Value for 'purgeState' must be 'documents_queued' or 'documents_and_metadata_queued'."
}
```

The message is "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Value for 'purgeState' must be 'documents_queued' or 'documents_and_metadata_queued'", but according to the docs, I shouldn't need to supply those parameter if the status is "voided" and I have a voided reason.

Is there a way to void an envelope using the DocuSign C# Client?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the envelope.PurgeState was set to "unpurged" when the envelope was loaded and that was passed to the API call. So even though I didn't explicitly set a PurgeState, it thought I was trying to perform the purge action with invalid parameters.

I was able to solve this by explicitly unsetting the envelope.PurgeState:

```
envelope.Status = "voided";
envelope.VoidedReason = "This envelope was voided by " + currentUserName;
envelope.PurgeState = null;
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question but I want to add that you don't need to call the API to get the original envelope object, just set the properties you need and send the Update call.

```
    public EnvelopeUpdateSummary VoidRequest(string envelopeId, string message)
    {
        var envelope = new Envelope()
        {
            Status = "voided",
            VoidedReason = message
        };

        var updateSummary = EnvelopesApi.Update(AccountId, envelopeId, envelope);
        return updateSummary;
    }
```

You can check the documentation: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/

Comment: Down vote: When I run this code, I get: Error calling Update: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. The specified integrator key was not found or is disabled. An integrator key was not specified.

Comment: @pianocomposer, this answer is from 3 years ago. For sure your environment now is not the same of mine back at 2018.  Hope you find a solution that help you out. Best Regards

Comment: @pianocomposer that will be related to your Oauth/JWT configuration - completely unrelated to this answer

Answer (score 0):

You must set the access token. I got that code straight from DocuSign support. Otherwise you get an integration key missing error. The PurgeState line is not necessary, but it solves a problem mentioned above. None of the code above worked for me  until I added the default configuration header.

```
                        var apiClient = new ApiClient(config.host);
                    // sets the integrator key
                    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + config.tokenInfo.access_token);
                    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

                    var env = new Envelope();
                    env.Status = "voided";
                    env.VoidedReason = "Entity requested void of PDF";
                    env.PurgeState = null;

                    envelopesApi.Update(config.targetAccountId, envelope.EnvelopeId, env);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot void envelopes that are in a Terminal state (i.e Completed or Voided), can you confirm the status of the envelope you're trying to void?

Comment: This is worth further investigation. The error message provided looks like an attempt to purge (delete) envelope documents/metadata as opposed to voiding (cancel) the transaction. If you try to void an envelope which is already voided the error message would be: "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_CANNOT_VOID_INVALID_STATE",
  "message": "Only envelopes in the 'Sent' or 'Delivered' states may be voided."

Comment: The Status of the envelope I was trying to void was In Process / Sent. I will update the question to clarify